# Tag cleanup: [electronics]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[electronics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/electronics) appears to be a pretty useless, undefined tag.  Many of the questions contain this tag only because computers and related devices use electronics.  Aside from that, usage includes:

- specific components or devices that have their own tags
- requests for software or hardware recommendations
- discussions of various vulnerabilities, which are covered by specific tags
- failure, troubleshooting, diagnostics, and repair; all covered by existing tags

Recommend just zapping it.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. Useless meta tag, recommend burinating and blacklisting.